# How to not repeat variables inside methods?

Tags: python, review

the variables `self.ledger` inside a class displays some deposits and withdraws in this way:

```
[{'amount': 50, 'description': 'Santa Claus arrived'}, {'amount': -12.5, 'description': 'Thiefs arrived'}]
```

The 2 methods `withdraw` and `deposit` append information into `self.ledger` each time they're called.

Here is the function to get the balance:

```
def get_balance(self):
   self.Alldeposited = sum([Transaction["amount"] for Transaction in self.ledger if Transaction["amount"] > 0])
   self.Allwithdrawn = abs(sum([Transaction["amount"] for Transaction in self.ledger if Transaction["amount"] < 0]))
   self.balance = self.Alldeposited - self.Allwithdrawn
   return self.balance
```

Here is the function to get the percentage spent:

```
def percentage_spent(self):
    self.Alldeposited = sum([Transaction["amount"] for Transaction in self.ledger if Transaction["amount"] > 0])
    self.Allwithdrawn = abs(sum([Transaction["amount"] for Transaction in self.ledger if Transaction["amount"] < 0]))
    Percentage = round(((self.Allwithdrawn*100)/self.Alldeposited),-1)
    return Percentage
```

As you can see the code is repetitive, how could I make it less repetitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this issue: either you keep track, each time you make a transaction, of the total deposited so far, and total withdrawn so far (which is the most efficient), or you simply re-calculate it each time. I would recommend going for the first solution, but since you seem to be recomputing it each time, it must not be a problem for you.

### First solution: recompute it each time

Using `@property`, you can make something that looks like an attribute, but whose value is actually computed each time you access it (and you can't write it). Just what we need!

```py
class Whatever:
   [...]
   @property
   def all_deposited(self):
      return sum(transaction["amount"] for transaction in self.ledger if transaction["amount"] > 0)
   @property
   def all_withdrawn(self):
      return sum(-transaction["amount"] for transaction in self.ledger if transaction["amount"] < 0)
```

### Second solution: keep track of withdrawn and deposited money so far

```py
class Whatever:
   def __init__(self, ...):
      [...]
      self.all_deposited = 0
      self.all_withdrawn = 0
   [...]
   def deposit(self, amount, ...): # I don't know what the real signature is
      [...]
      self.all_deposited += amount
   def withdraw(self, amount, ...):
      [...]
      self.all_withdrawn += amount
```

Then, in both cases, you can access these amounts as attributes:

```py
def percentage_spent(self):
    percentage = round(((self.all_withdrawn*100)/self.all_deposited),-1)
    return percentage

def get_balance(self):
   self.balance = self.all_deposited - self.all_withdrawn
   return self.balance
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the common functionality to its own function, or split it into two distinct ones:

```
def deposited_and_withdrawn():
    return {
        'deposited': sum([Transaction["amount"] for Transaction in self.ledger if Transaction["amount"] > 0])
        'withdrawn': abs(sum([Transaction["amount"] for Transaction in self.ledger if Transaction["amount"] < 0]))
    }
```

or split it further:

```
def deposited():
    return sum([Transaction["amount"] for Transaction in self.ledger if Transaction["amount"] > 0])

def withdrawn():
    return abs(sum([Transaction["amount"] for Transaction in self.ledger if Transaction["amount"] < 0]))
```

I don't see the need to avoid repetition inside the `sum` for a small code block as this (otherwise you could move the comparison out as a lambda function and then give that to a "transaction summer"-function):

```
def transaction_summer(transactions, filter_):
    return sum([transaction["amount"] for transaction in transactions if filter_(transaction)]

def withdrawn():
    return abs(self.transaction_summer(self.ledger, lambda x: x['amount'] < 0))
```

If you only need this to operate on the ledger, rename the method to `ledger_summer` and drop the `transactions` argument if it makes the code clearer to you.